# Can Excel autofill one range but copy another in the same autofill operation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel which I need to copy 80 times, and have each one be numbered sequentially.
(Table 1, Table 2, Table 3 ... Table 80)

However, one of the columns in this table contains the text (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6).

When I drag the autofill thing down to copy the table, it auto increments both the Table numbers and the P numbers, continuing on from P7. I can set the autofill to copy instead of autofill, but then the Table numbers don't get incremented either.

Can I have my cake and eat it too by having one thing increment and one thing not?

[The table I'm trying to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxS9W.png)

[What happens when I drag down the autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hL6k.png)

[What I want to happen (I did this manually by copy/pasting, but don't want to do that 80 times)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6cnM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in the first row where the list of Periods are:

```
="P"&SEQUENCE(6)
```

[image]

Now drag down as before and it should work as you wanted.

[image]

Comment: I copied that formula into the cell that said P1, and it's giving me a #NAME? error...

Comment: I have figured out that SEQUENCE only works in Office 365, not Office 2019. I switched to using 365 and now your solution works perfectly! Thank you very much.